# Vertical Table Alignment - the nightmare

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, ieeetran, ieee-style

People, I've looked to multiple questions already asked about this theme but I can't find a straight answer! I have the following table:

[image]

And, as you can see, there are multiple problems! I have that " --- " in the first box, I dont know why.. and then, any of the cell arrays is aligned! And so the numbers are not perceptible...

Here goes the code, please help me.

```
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}b{#1}}

\begin{table*}[!t]
    \centering
    \caption{Information regarding the MOIs}\label{tab:L2}
  \begin{tabular}{R{1.3cm}*{1}{C{.8cm}}|*{2}{C{1cm}}|*{2}{C{1cm}}|*{2}{C{1cm}}|*{4}{C{1.3cm}}}|
    &  &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Velocity(ms$^{-1}$)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Acceleration(ms$^{-2}$)}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Jerk(ms$^{-3}$)}} \\ 
 \textbf{Sz Type} & \textbf{\#MOIs} & \textbf{Median} & \textbf{Std} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Std} & \textbf{Mean} & \textbf{Std} & \textbf{MD (m)} & \textbf{CD (m)} &  \textbf{MOI duration (s)} \\ \hline
      %\midrule
        %\midline
        TLE & 19 & 0.086 $\pm$ 0.064 & 0.58 $\pm$ 0.41 & 12 $\pm$ 8.4 & 38 $\pm$ 33 & 345 $\pm$ 287 & 1,204 $\pm$ 1,151 & 0.15 $\pm$ 0.11 & 6.3 $\pm$ 4.2 & 23 $\pm$ 6.6     \\
 ex-TLE & 23 & 0.068 $\pm$ 0.063 & 0.46 $\pm$ 0.29 & 8.6 $\pm$ 4.6 & 23 $\pm$ 17& 172 $\pm$ 127 & 574 $\pm$ 506       & 0.44 $\pm$ 0.29 & 7.6 $\pm$ 2.9 & 35 $\pm$ 10     \\ \hline
      %\bottomrule
        P & n.a. & n.s & n.s & n.s & n.s & \textless  0.04 & n.s & \textless  0.001 & n.s & \textless  0.01     \\ \hline
        %Note. Values are given as mean $\pm$ SD. n.a., not applicable. n.s., not significant \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{center}
```

Also, I want to add this line in the end of the table,

```
%Note. Values are given as mean $\pm$ SD. n.a., not applicable. n.s., not significant
```

but I can't do it. Thanks

Comment: is the table code what was actually used for the output as shown?  the first-column heading "MOI Type" in the output appears as "Sz Type" in the code.  ???

Comment: The table definition line needs to have the | moved inside the brace just before it.  ie  use |}  not }|     This is causing the dash to appear the first cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is another solution, using `siunitx, booktabs, makecell` and `threeparttable`. With a small margin (1.8cm) the table fits into the margins if the font size is set to `\small`. Hope to have turned nightmare into a mellow dream…

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[margin=1.8cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, caption, booktabs, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{bc}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!t]%
  \sisetup{table-number-alignment = center, separate-uncertainty,table-align-uncertainty = true, detect-weight, zero-decimal-to-integer}
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}\small\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \centering
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Information regarding the MOIs}\label{tab:L1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}rc%
        S[table-format = 1.3(3)]
        S[table-format=1.2(2)]
        S[table-format = 2.1(1)]
        S[table-format=2(2)]
        S[table-format=3(3)]
        S[table-format=4(4)]
        S[table-format=1.2(2)]
        S[table-format=1.1(2)]
        S[table-format=2(2)]@{}}
        \toprule
        & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Velocity\\ (\si{\m\per\s})}} &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Acceleration\\ (\si{\m\per\s\squared})}} &
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Jerk\\ (\si{\m\per\s\cubed})}} \\[-6ex]
        \thead{Sz Type} & \thead{\#MOIs} & {\thead{Median}} & {\thead{Std}} & {\thead{Mean}} & {\thead{Std}} & {\thead{Mean}} & {\thead{Std}} & {\thead{MD (m)}} & {\thead{CD (m)}} & {\thead{MOI \\ duration \\(s)}} \\
        \midrule
        TLE & 19 & 0.086 (64) & 0.58 (41) & 12 (84) & 38 (33) & 345 (287) & 1204 (1151) & 0.15 (11) & 6.3 (42) & 23. (66) \\
        \addlinespace
        ex-TLE & 23 & 0.068 (63) & 0.46 (29) & 8.6 (46) & 23 (17) & 172 (127) &574 (506) & 0.44 (29) & 7.6 (29) & 35 (10) \\
        \midrule
        P & n.a. & {n.s.} & {n.s.} & {n.s.} & {n.s.} & {< 0.04} & {n.s.} & {< 0.001} & {n.s.} & {< 0.01} \\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}[online]\medskip\footnotesize
        \item[\em Note. ]Values are given as mean $\pm$ SD. n.a.: not applicable. n.s.: not significant
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't compile the code - it gives multiple errors. I've made sure to use the correct packages...

Comment: newbie mistake, it is perfectly WORKING! THANKS SO MUCH MAN YOU ROCK!!!!!!!

Comment: @user2205242: I posted the code of a draft, the final code is much simpler. I'll post it in a moment.

Comment: Thanks so much :) I also noticed that this code changed all the format of the text, but I guess that won't be a problem

Comment: Bernard, I want to make multiple tables, quite similar with this one, but with the difference being the number of columns in the right side of the table. I need a table ending with MD(m), like the first example and i need a table with an extra-column after the MOI duration (s). I guess this might be pretty straight-forward but I am not putting it right

Comment: @user2205242: I've posted the simpler code (no `\num` used). For your other questions/comments: I don't get what you mean with ‘change the format of the text’? Also, could you post a minimal example of what you'd like to have for your other tables? I suspect you should use a landscape oriented table.

Comment: Bernard, see the link attached. It is the same table, with the difference being the last element! [ http://imgur.com/choieHJ ] - I need one table with only one last element, and I need this one also, with 4 elements in the end [ http://imgur.com/OSAVQmk ] - I think the code is straightforward, but I cant just get it right...

Comment: @user2205242: I have the code for the first table and there's a small problem for the second one: I don't know if the commas in numbers are thousand separators or if you mixed up decimal dots and decimal commas.Knowing that can impact the code. Could you check the linked files?

Comment: the commas are thousand separators!

Comment: However one of the tables has column with `180,9 ± 162,2` which can't be a decimal separator.So?

Comment: That indeed should be a "." - therefore 180.9 and 162.2. Sorry for the delay in answering

Comment: Ang also (row below, same column) `102.2 ± 864.9`, I suppose? Where can I upload the files?

Comment: Yep! send me by e-mail please - liv3_91@hotmail.com

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be too much data to put into one landscape table really, I used a small font
and stole some margins but really it needs a different layout of some subject knowledge to compress the data (eg reduce the number of decimal places in some fields)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.25}

\begin{table*}[!t]
    \centering
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \caption{Information regarding the MOIs}\label{tab:L2}

\hspace*{-3cm}\begin{tabular}{
lr
d{1.3}@{${}\pm{}$}d{1.3} d{1.2}@{${}\pm{}$}d{1.2} 
d{2.1}@{${}\pm{}$}d{1.1} d{2.0}@{${}\pm{}$}d{2.0} 
d{3.0}@{${}\pm{}$}d{3.0} d{3.0}@{${}\pm{}$}d{5.0} 
d{1.2}@{${}\pm{}$}d{1.2} d{1.1}@{${}\pm{}$}d{1.1} d{2.0}@{${}\pm{}$}d{2.1} 
cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc
}
\toprule

    &  &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Velocity(ms$^{-1}$)}} &
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Acceleration(ms$^{-2}$)}} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Jerk(ms$^{-3}$)}} \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Type}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\#}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Median}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Std}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Mean}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Std}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Mean}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Std}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{MD (m)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{CD (m)}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{(s)}} \\ 
      \midrule
              TLE & 19 & 0.086 & 0.064 & 0.58 & 0.41 & 12 & 8.4 & 38 & 33 & 345 & 287 & 1,204 & 1,151 & 0.15 & 0.11 & 6.3 & 4.2 & 23 & 6.6     \\
 ex-TLE & 23 & 0.068 & 0.063 & 0.46 & 0.29 & 8.6 & 4.6 & 23 & 17& 172 & 127 & 574 & 506       & 0.44 & 0.29 & 7.6 & 2.9 & 35 & 10     \\
      \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{P} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{n.a.}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{n.s}& 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{n.s}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{n.s}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{n.s}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{${}<  0.04$} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{n.s}&
\multicolumn{2}{c}{${}<  0.001$} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{n.s} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{${}<  0.01$}   \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\hspace*{-3cm}

\smallskip

        Note. Values are given as mean $\pm$ SD. n.a., not applicable. n.s., not significant 
\end{table*}


\end{document}
```